# Is it possible to replace my phone wires t network wires in the walls?

Tags: walls, installation, wire

In my house I have telephone access point in each room. Is it possible to replace them with network cables?

I have tried every option I know to get WIFI signal in my top floor but always getting poor signal or none.

Do I need professional to do so? Or can I do it alone.

I don't know if this is the right place for this question but I trust this site!

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking of using the existing phone wires to pull ethernet cable through the walls, the answer is most likely no.  The phone wire is almost certainly smaller, so it will probably be passing through smaller holes. On top of that, it is likely stapled to the framing.

That said, fishing new wire through the walls usually isn't that hard if you have access to the bottoms and tops of the interior walls in the basement and the attic. The easiest way would typically be to wire the first floor in a star pattern from the basement, and the top floor in a star pattern from the attic, then connect them with one cable running from basement to attic. Good places to try and fish a basement to attic cable would be alongside the main vent stack for your plumbing or through a wet wall. If you don't want to put individual jacks in the walls, you can always just run one cable and put a second access point on the upper floor.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, the best answer is "it depends". Very OFTEN one can, but not always. A 2nd/3rd floor gets problematic unless you have a chase (like a chimney chase, for example) that you could use to route the cable upstairs, or you're OK with stapling new cable along the bottoms of the mopboards/baseboards and down the stairs. Under the edge of a carpet is ideal. If you have all "hard floors" and exposed cables are out of the question and you have no accessible chase, you're likely to have a hard time getting cables run across the gap between one floor's top plate and the next floor's sill plate. ANYONE is likely to have a hard time doing THAT, professional or amateur.

If you DO have carpeting, you can nearly always tug the veriest edge up with a pair of needlenose pliers, barely enough to tuck the cable under the edge. For stapling to mopboards/baseboards, you'll need a "cable stapler" built specifically for round cable, and you'll need some practice with it - if a cable staple penetrates the cable, it may cause you no end of grief. In either of these cases, you can certainly do the job yourself if you're comfortable with tools.

Have you tried running a two-antenna wireless router on each floor, with one antenna pointed straight up and the other horizontal? That may help.

Comment: Running cables under carpet, and on the exterior of walls is hacky and unprofessional.

Comment: Excuse me? Phone/network cables? It's EXTREMELY common when there's no great access from one floor to the next, and when the owner doesn't want to open up sheetrock, plaster, or other wall coverings. OK, I'll grant that in YOUR opinion it may be hacky or unprofessional, but I've worked in numerous buildings in which that was the only practical way to achieve the goal.

Comment: BTW... "professional" only means people make money doing it. Some of the truly "professional" workmanship out there is of ABYSMALLY poor "quality" as I define "quality".